# Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

When googling about Maclaurin series, I found this:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n
\\
\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{1-(1-x)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x)^n
\\
\frac{1}{x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x^2)^n
\\
\frac{1}{(2-x)^2} & = & \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-(2-x)^2)^n)
\\
& = & \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x^2 +4x - 3)^n
\\
& = & \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (x - 3)^n (x - 1)^n
\end{eqnarray*}$$

There appears to be problem regarding the convergence at $x = 0$. I don't see where the mistake in the working is, and then how to continue until we get the standard answer for power series of $\frac{1}{(2-x)^2}$? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That series from the starting is valid if
$$|x|<1$$

And you got the hint now.

Find the convergence interaiew..usign this from the starting..and you will see why X=0 gives divergence result

At last you should get
$$|1-(2-x)^2|<1$$
Here is the graph showing the above region:
[image]

which on  solving gives the approximate solution interval as
$$0.58<x<2\;\;\;\; \cup \;\;\;\;2<x<3.41$$

So,

> $x=0$ not lies in this interval

Comment: Stupid me, should have checked the radius of convergence from the beginning. Thank you

Comment: @Magenta can u please do a vote up or accept it as final asnwer .. if you think you got your answer in any of the solutions provided on this page

Comment: Sorry, how to do a vote up?

Comment: By clicking on upper triangle icon

Comment: Ok,  think I have done that.  Please tell me if there is something not correct.  Thank you

Comment: thanks ... you may see a tick mark,,, below that upper triangle...  you may chose any answer by clicking tick mark... so as to accept the answer of this posted question

Comment: I can only choose one answer?

Comment: yes u can chose only one as accepted answer ...and thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest another (standard) approach which seems much easier:

$$\frac{1}{(2-x)^2} = \left(\frac{1}{2-x}\right)'$$
$$\frac{1}{2-x} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2^n}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{(2-x)^2} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^{n-1}}{2^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)x^{n}}{2^{n+2}}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a big hint go get you started.

$\frac {1}{(2-x)^2} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac {1}{2-x}$

Comment: Thank you for the hint